# Is there a way to mark my Android app process "busy"?

Tags: android, kill

I have a downloader application on Android.

It shows a notification(in-progress, not dismissable) during the download
and it also catches a wakelock.
I even asks the user to disable Doze for my app.

However, battery-saving feature from various vendors seem to ignore it and kill it randomly.

Is there a way to mark my app process "busy",
so that it has a higher priority in the not-to-kill list?

Note that I'm not using a service in my app.
Regular activity spawns up a thread and download is handled from there.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I'm not using a service in my app

That would be the lion's share of your problem.

> Regular activity spawns up a thread and download is handled from there.

That means that Android has no idea that you are doing anything that the user would value, when you're not in the foreground. Android will happily terminate your process to free up system RAM for other processes.

Use a service, perhaps an `IntentService` (since it already has a background thread for you, and it automatically shuts down once your work is complete). Convert your `Notification` into one for `startForeground()` on the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping a wakelock for a longish time then it is better to let the user know about it, use a foreground service as CommonsWare pointed out.

However, if your use case does not warrant any foreground behavior then I would recommend you use framework [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) that plays very well with doze and app standby as well.
For earlier than API 21 you may use [JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) API.

You can read the more details [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html).